# How to filter out fluentd logs to just logs and remove all metadata

Tags: kubernetes, logging, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to setup fluentd into my kubernetes cluster and I am able to push the logs. Only issue is it is pushing in json format with a lot of extra junk which I don't need.

Here is how the logs are looking right now

```
{
    "log": "ACTUAL LOG CONTENT",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "docker": {
        "container_id": "foo-bar"
    },
    "kubernetes": {
        "container_name": "foo-bar",
        "namespace_name": "foo-bar",
        "pod_name": "foo-bar",
        "pod_id": "foo-bar",
        "labels": {
            "application": "foo-bar",
            "pod-template-hash": "foo-bar"
        },
        "host": "foo-bar",
        "master_url": "foo-bar",
        "namespace_id": "foo-bar",
        "namespace_labels": {
            "kubernetes_io/metadata_name": "foo-bar"
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to be something like this, all the other data should be scraped.

```
"log": "ACTUAL LOG CONTENT"
```

or just

```
ACTUAL LOG CONTENT
```

Unfortunately I am not able to understand the usage of filters, parse, match in documentation.

Anyone knows hot to setup the Config for this?

My Config map has this data in it

```
  containers.conf: |
    <source>
      @type tail
      @id in_tail_container_logs
      @label @containers
      path /var/log/containers/*_foo-bar_*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
      tag *
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type json
        time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
      </parse>
    </source>

    <label @containers>
      <filter **>
        @type kubernetes_metadata
        @id filter_kube_metadata
      </filter>

      <filter **>
        @type record_transformer
        @id filter_containers_stream_transformer
        <record>
          stream_name ${tag_parts[3]}
        </record>
      </filter>

      <match **>
        @type cloudwatch_logs
        @id out_cloudwatch_logs_containers
        region "#{ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')}"
        log_group_name "/EKS-LOGS/#{ENV.fetch('AWS_EKS_CLUSTER_NAME')}/containers"
        log_stream_name_key stream_name
        remove_log_stream_name_key true
        auto_create_stream true
        <buffer>
          flush_interval 5
          chunk_limit_size 2m
          queued_chunks_limit_size 32
          retry_forever true
        </buffer>
      </match>
    </label>
  fluent.conf: |
    @include containers.conf

    <match fluent.**>
      @type null
    </match>
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer with its [`keep_keys`](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#keep_keys) and [`renew_record`](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#renew_record) options.